# Shell scriptでKDE neon（Ubuntuベース）のソフトウェアのインストールと設定を自動化したいです。

Tags: ubuntu, shellscript

**現象**
Linux（KDE neon）のセットアップを自動化するshell scriptを実行したところ、下記内容が出力されます。

```
…省略

/var/log/clamav/freshclam.log {
     rotate 12
     weekly
     compress
     delaycompress
     missingok
     create 640  clamav adm
     postrotate
     if [ -d /run/systemd/system ]; then
         systemctl -q is-active clamav-freshclam && systemctl kill --signal=SIGHUP clamav-freshclam || true
     else
         invoke-rc.d clamav-freshclam reload-log > /dev/null || true
     fi
     endscript
     }
#Automatically Generated by clamav-daemon postinst
#To reconfigure clamd run #dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon
#Please read /usr/share/doc/clamav-daemon/README.Debian.gz for details
LocalSocket /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl
FixStaleSocket true
LocalSocketGroup clamav
LocalSocketMode 666
# TemporaryDirectory is not set to its default /tmp here to make overriding
# the default with environment variables TMPDIR/TMP/TEMP possible
#User clamav
ScanMail true
ScanArchive true
ArchiveBlockEncrypted false
MaxDirectoryRecursion 15
FollowDirectorySymlinks false
FollowFileSymlinks false
ReadTimeout 180
MaxThreads 12

省略…
```

**期待値**
Clam AVやその他のソフトウェアのインストールと設定をshell scriptで自動化したいです。

**再現手順**
KDE neonで`superUser.sh`と`autoSetup.sh`を同じディレクトリに入れて、`superUser.sh`を実行すると再現できます。

`superUser.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ./autoSetup.sh
```

`autoSetup.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# homeディレクトリを英語にする
echo "homeディレクトリを英語にします"
LANG=C xdg-user-dirs-update --force

# Update
echo "Updateします"
apt update

# Upgrade
echo "Upgradeします"
apt upgrade

# Vimをインストール
echo "Vimをインストールします"
apt install vim

# mozcをインストール
echo "日本語インプットメソッド「mozc」をインストールします"
apt install ibus-mozc

# Clam AVのインストールと設定
echo "Clam AVをインストールします"
apt install clamav clamav-daemon
rm /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
touch /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
chown clamav:clamav /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log
mkdir -p /opt/script/
touch /opt/script/clam-full.sh
chmod 200 /opt/script/clam-full.sh
sed -e "s/create 640 adm clamav/create 640 clamav clamav/g" /etc/logrotate.d/clamav-freshclam
echo "#!/bin/sh \\n
echo ========================================= \\n
date \\n 
hostname \\n
clamscan / \ \\n
     --infected \ \\n
     --recursive \ \\n
     --log=/var/log/clamav/clamscan.log \\n
     --move=/var/log/clamav/virus \ \\n
     --exclude-dir=^/boot \ \\n
     --exclude-dir=^/sys \ \\n
     --exclude-dir=^/proc \ \\n
     --exclude-dir=^/dev \ \\n
     --exclude-dir=^/var/log/clamav/virus \\n

# --infected 感染を検出したファイルのみを結果に出力 \\n
# --recursive 指定ディレクトリ以下を再帰的に検査 圧縮ファイルは解凍して検査 \\n
# --log=FILE ログファイル \\n
# --move=DIR 感染を検出したファイルの隔離先 \\n
# --remove 感染を検出したファイルを削除 \\n
# --exclude=FILE 　　検査除外ファイル（パターンで指定） \\n
# --exclude-dir=DIR　検査除外ディレクトリ（パターンで指定） \\n

if [ $? = 0 ]; then \\n
  echo 'ウイルス未検出.' \\n
else \\n
  echo 'ウイルス検出!!' \\n
fi" >> /opt/script/clam-full.sh 
chmod +x /opt/script/clam-full.sh
mkdir -p /var/log/clamav/virus
echo "0 0 * * * /opt/script/clam-full.sh >> /var/log/clamav/clamav_scan.log \\n
0 7 * * * /opt/script/clam-full.sh >> /var/log/clamav/clamav_scan.log \\n
0 10 * * * /opt/script/clam-full.sh >> /var/log/clamav/clamav_scan.log \\n
0 13 * * * /opt/script/clam-full.sh >> /var/log/clamav/clamav_scan.log \\n
0 16 * * * /opt/script/clam-full.sh >> /var/log/clamav/clamav_scan.log \\n
0 19 * * * /opt/script/clam-full.sh >> /var/log/clamav/clamav_scan.log \\n" >> /etc/crontab
sed -e "s/User clamav/#User clamav/g" /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
```

**参考リンク**
[【Ubuntu 20.04/18.04 LTS Server】ClamAVで定期的にウイルスチェックし、メール通知する](https://www.yokoweb.net/2017/04/15/ubuntu-server-clamav/#toc4)

Comment: 自分で作るのもありですが、Ansibleなどのプロビジョニングツールで自動化するのもいいでよ。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スクリプトの中で何箇所か `sed` コマンドを実行していますが、sed は **フィルタ結果を標準出力に表示するため**、あなたの書いたスクリプトでは `/etc/logrotate.d/clamav-freshclam`, `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf` のフィルタ (置換) 結果が画面に出力されているのだと思います。

結果が画面 (標準出力) に表示されているだけで、元のファイルは書き換わりません。

---

元のファイルを直接書き換えたい場合には、sed の `-i` オプションを使います。

```
$ sed -i -e "s/User clamav/#User clamav/g" /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
```

バックアップを残したい場合には、`-i` オプションに (空白を開けずに) 任意の拡張子を指定します。

```
$ sed -i.bak -e "s/User clamav/#User clamav/g" /etc/clamav/clamd.conf
```